# Deploy JAR to ASG behind ELB using github actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, github-actions, autoscaling, aws-application-load-balancer

Hi I know how to deploy jar to single EC2
but wondering how to deploy jar to multiple EC2 which combined with AutoScaling group behind Application load balancer?

```
- name: Deploy to EC2
  run: |
    scp -i /path/to/your/ssh-key.pem target/your-app.jar ec2-user@your-ec2-instance:/path/on/ec2/
    ssh -i /path/to/your/ssh-key.pem ec2-user@your-ec2-instance "sudo systemctl stop your-app.service && nohup java -jar /path/on/ec2/your-app.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Answer (score 1):

As your command, I guess you are using in-place update strategy, which is not a good solution for ASG because some reasons:

- The Instance number in the ASG is dynamic, it will be changed in scale in/out action. That mean the IP address list also dynamic. You need an extend process to get the list of IP before run the script
- On scale out event, a new instance instantiated by image that defined in launch configuration or launch template. That mean your command "scp" and "ssh" may not effected those new instance

There are at lest 2 strategies to integrate CICD with Autoscaling Group and ASG:

**Option 1. Deploy using AWS CodeDeploy:**

- Step 1.1: Github Action run the CI and then upload artifact to AWS s3.
- Step 1.2: An S3 upload event will trigger AWS CodeDeploy to deploy new version of application to the EC2 instances in ASG
- Step 1.3: On scale out event, ASG [lifecycle hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks-overview.html) trigger AWS CodeDeploy to deploy the latest version of application to the new instance

You can get the more detail of logic of AWS CodePipeline and ASG in the blog: [Under the Hood: AWS CodeDeploy and Auto Scaling Integration](https://aws.amazon.com/vi/blogs/devops/under-the-hood-aws-codedeploy-and-auto-scaling-integration/)

**Option 2: Rebuild EC2 image and update it to launch template/launch configuration.**

You can do it with Hashicorp packer or AWS Instance builder. This is not familial to me, so I just able to give you the keyword. Let google and you will get many result for it

- [awslabs/ami-builder-packer](https://github.com/awslabs/ami-builder-packer)
- [Create a pipeline and AMI using CodePipeline and HashiCorp Packer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/create-a-pipeline-and-ami-using-codepipeline-and-hashicorp-packer.html)

By the way, you can using the ASG life cycle hook to trigger github action to run deployment step to the new instance using [github action API](https://docs.github.com/fr/rest/actions?apiVersion=2022-11-28) (custom from the option 1)